# Read each table of pdf and assign a search word that appears at top of table to it

Tags: python, nlp, tabula

I am able to read each table of pdf using tabula library and the output of table is as follows. Imagine in the page 6th we only have 2 tables.

The code for execrating tables:

```
mytable = tabula.io.read_pdf("x.pdf", pages = 6, multiple_tables = True)
```

```
mytable[0]

    Val     Label   %
0   0.0     nan     100.0 %
1   NaN     Total   100%
```

```
mytable[1]

    Val     Label   %
0   0.0     a       100.0 %
0   4.0     b       6 %
1   NaN     Total   100%
```

I can extract the whole text of page 6 with code as follows :

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
def text_extractor(path):
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        reader = PdfReader (f)
        page = reader.pages[5]
        print(page)
        print('Page type: {}'.format(str(type(page))))
        text = page.extract_text()
        print(text)
    return text

path = "x.pdf"
c= text_extractor(path)
```

I also have some keyword that appears at the top of each table in pdf file. one keyword at the top of each table randomly.

I already have a list of keywords as

```
search keywords = ["id","type", "name", etc]
```

The problem is I want to search and assign each of this keyword that appears at the top of table to the table itself, the format really doesn't matter can be dictionary or creating a column in the table. I want to know how can I assign this search key that appears at top of table to table itself?

Comment: You have two tables in the example, where are the keywords in them?

Comment: Keywords are in the text as I explained above each table there is a keyword.